# Unable to set socket options IPV6 multicast : No such device error

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, ipv6, multicast

I am working on `linux Ubuntu 14.04` and trying to multicast using IPv6. I have a link local address of `fe80::9a90:96ff:fe98:a985`. Running the following code :

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int sd;
  struct in6_addr localInterface;
  /* Create a datagram socket on which to send/receive. */
  sd = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

  if(sd < 0) {
    perror("Opening datagram socket error");
    exit(1);
  }
  else {
    printf("Opening the datagram socket...OK.\n");
  }

  /* Set local interface for outbound multicast datagrams. */
  /* The IP address specified must be associated with a local, */
  /* multicast capable interface. */
  inet_pton (AF_INET6, "fe80::9a90:96ff:fe98:a985", &(localInterface.s6_addr));

  if(setsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_MULTICAST_IF, (char *)&localInterface, sizeof(localInterface)) < 0)
    {
      perror("Setting local interface error");
      printf ("%d\n", errno);
      exit(1);
    }
  else {
    printf("Setting the local interface...OK\n");
  }

}
```

gives the error : `Setting local interface error : No such device`

I have tested multicast to work with `IPv4` and also successfully tested that `IPv6` works by pinging a local node using `ping6` command.

Comment: After a lot of search, I figured out that in IPv6, the 3rd and 4th argument of setsockopt have changed to the index of the send interface. After making the changes, though, I am still not able to send successfully (there are no packets captured in tcpdump).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a few adjustments I was able to modify your program to get it to send multicast packets (that show up in WireShark) on my Mac (running OS/X 10.10.5).  I haven't tried it under other OS's, but it should more or less work on other OS's as well.

Note that the program has hard-coded the interface number to 4, since that is what en0 is on my computer; the interface number will likely be different on your computer, and for a generally useful program you'd want to discover the correct interface number dynamically (using [getifaddrs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html)() or [GetAdaptersAddresses](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365915(v=vs.85).aspx)() or similar); it's only hard-coded here for simplicity.

Modified program follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
   int sd = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
   if(sd < 0)
   {
      perror("Opening datagram socket error");
      exit(1);
   }
   else printf("Opening the datagram socket...OK.\n");

   // 4 is the interface ID (scope_id) of interface en0 on my Mac,
   // as printed by ifconfig; the appropriate interface index 
   // value on your computer will likely be different  --jaf
   int my_network_devices_scope_id = 4;

   if(setsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_MULTICAST_IF, (char *)&my_network_devices_scope_id, sizeof(my_network_devices_scope_id)) < 0)
   {
       perror("Setting local interface error");
       printf ("%d\n", errno);
       exit(1);
   }
   else printf("Setting the local interface...OK\n");

   struct sockaddr_in6 multicastIP;
   multicastIP.sin6_family   = AF_INET6;
   multicastIP.sin6_scope_id = my_network_devices_scope_id;
   multicastIP.sin6_port     = htons(9999);  // destination port chosen at random
   inet_pton(AF_INET6, "ff12::bead:cede:deed:feed", &multicastIP.sin6_addr.s6_addr);  // a multicast address I chose at random

   while(1)
   {
       char buf[] = "hello";
       if (sendto(sd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (const struct sockaddr *) &multicastIP, sizeof(multicastIP)) == sizeof(buf))
       {
          printf("Sent a %i-byte multicast packet!\n", (int) sizeof(buf));
       }
       else perror("sendto");

       sleep(1);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works. One of the problems I had was the multicast address "ff5e::/16", which after changing to your random one, works perfectly.